# EventProcessorHost method - Do I need an azure blob storage and lease container for event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I'm using the EventProcessorHost() method in the Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor library and it seems that in addition to an event hub library, I need to specify a storage connection string and a lease container name - as parameters.

Do I need to create an azure blob storage and also - where can I find the lease container name?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a storage account, and lease container name is your actual container name. 
So create a container within your blob storage, and specify that container name as your lease container name in constructor of EventProcessorHost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you need Azure storage container to maintain leaser checker for your application. You just need to provide connection string of storage account and you have to provide container name in your application , your application will create storage container in blob automatically.